# Slim application Autoloading

Tags: php, slim, psr-4

I am newbie on REST and Slim applications.

I was not able to autoload some classes:

> Type: RuntimeException Message: Callable UserController does not exist
>   File: /var/www/fdes/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/CallableResolver.php Line:
>   90
>
> #0 /var/www/fdes/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/CallableResolver.php(61): Slim\CallableResolver->resolveCallable('UserController', 'login')
>   #1 /var/www/fdes/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/CallableResolverAwareTrait.php(45):
>   Slim\CallableResolver->resolve('UserController:...')
>   #2 /var/www/fdes/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Route.php(351): Slim\Routable->resolveCallable('UserController:...')

composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    }
```

Directory Structure:

```
fdes\app\api\Controllers\User\UserController.php
```

UserController.php:

```
namespace Api\Controllers\User;

use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;
use Respect\Validation\Validator as v;

class UserController extends BaseController {

    protected $db;
```

Can u guys let me  know what i am missing here?

Thanks Folks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your namespace of your controller is wrong.
The namespace should be `namspace App\Api\Controllers\User`.

Furthermore it would be good if your folder structure would be identical to your namespace. So `api` should be `Api`, etc.

Comment: Yes, but remember that namespaces in php are case insensitive, so that means you can have dir `api` and use namespace `API` or `Api`. Of course, it's not a good practise.